# How to make event name badges with background image and coloured text?

Tags: civievent

I've been looking around in 4.7.23, Drupal latest, trying to suss how to make Event name badges with a custom background, and coloured text.

I've found several things that go part of the way, as well as some incompleteness in places. So I thought I'd compile what I've found as a way to help puzzle through this.

Firstly, it is possible to make new event name badges and also new badge layouts:

- Make new or customised layouts using the option group, 'Name Badge Format Options'
  (civicrm/admin/options?gid=111&reset=1).
- Then, this [very helpful answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11266/how-do-i-add-a-custom-name-badge) shows how to add or customise entries in this list, for eg by customizing the Avery 5395 entry.
- The formats in this list will then be available when making new
  custom name badge layouts here: Admin > CiviEvent > Event Name Badge
  Layouts. (civicrm/admin/badgelayout?action=add&reset=1).
- This is a helpful UI for making name badges, with many image and
  text size/style options.  But no background images or font colour
  options are available.

Secondly, there is another option group called Event Name Badge, at civicrm/admin/options?gid=49&reset=1. I couldn't spot how and where these are used. This contains helpful sounding possibilities including 'You can set your own background image'. So I'd love to know how to use this.

And finally, there is a broken link in the [documentation on event name badges](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Name+Badge+Administration%2C+Customization): The link to [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/event-badges) returns a 404.

In conclusion, I'm no closer to finding out how to make coloured text or background images, but at least I have more understanding the possibilities and the road-map of event name badges! Any suggestions about font colour and background are welcome...  :-)